# Terminal-command to retrieve version of log4j in NextcloudPi (Raspbian) system?

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian, nextcloud

> NCSC recommends updating to version 2.15.0 or later, and – where not
> possible – mitigating the flaw in Log4j 2.10 and later by setting
> system property "log4j2.formatMsgNoLookups" to "true" or removing the
> JndiLookup class from the classpath.

Source: https://www.zdnet.com/article/log4j-zero-day-flaw-what-you-need-to-know-and-how-to-protect-yourself/

```
pi@nextcloudpi:~/log4j-detector-master $ uname -a
Linux nextcloudpi 5.10.63-v7+ #1496 SMP Wed Dec 1 15:58:11 GMT 2021 armv7l GNU/Linux
```

Is there a simple terminal command that can retrieve the version of log4j?

## Tests:

Test for Apache Webserver: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55107891

pi@nextcloudpi:~ $ `ps -acx|grep apache`

```
  705 ?        Ss     0:53 apache2
 1600 ?        Sl     0:01 apache2
 1601 ?        Sl     0:01 apache2
```

unzipped: `wget https://github.com/mergebase/log4j-detector/archive/refs/heads/master.zip`

```
pi@nextcloudpi:~/log4j-detector-master $ java -jar log4j-detector-2021.12.14.jar [path-to-scan] > hits.txt
-bash: java: command not found
```

I am reluctant to install a JDK on the NCP server.

Comment: Be aware that setting the config option is **not** sufficient to mitigate this: https://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2021-45046

Comment: If there is no "java" on that machine, then it's not vulnerable !

Answer (score 1):

While the log4j software can be bundled with third-party applications, you can retrieve the status of the liblog4j2-java OS package in Raspbian with:

```bsh
dpkg --get-selections | grep liblog4j2-java
```

This is based on the [Raspberry Connect](https://www.raspberryconnect.com/raspbian-packages/49-raspbian-aptget) page, under "Check what Packages are installed"

I determined the package name by searching the [Raspbian Java Packages](https://www.raspberryconnect.com/raspbian-packages/75-raspbian-java) page for log4j. Note that the "liblog4j1.2-java" is version 1 of log4j, while "liblog4j2-java" is version 2 of log4j, which has the [recent CVE](https://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2021-44228) you're looking at.

Comment: given that grep does not find the string `liblog4j`:  https://pastebin.com/raw/gCiDGH27   Can one  conclude that log4j is not installed and that NextCloudPi is not vulnerable to said CVE?

Comment: You could say that of the base OS installation, but not of an arbitrary server, given that an application could bring a copy of a vulnerable log4j, as I alluded to in the answer.